# Can node affinity cause pod eviction?

Tags: kubernetes, termination, kubernetes-jobs

I have a number of jobs running across multiple nodes within the cluster. Randomly, the pods begin terminating and a new pod is created by the job.

Each pod has a node affinity assigned to it, using preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution and a weight. Is it possible for the node affinity to cause the pod eviction?

I have tried to set a priority on the pods using a priority class, with a high priority and the preemption policy set to never, like below.

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority-nonpreempting
value: 1000000
preemptionPolicy: Never
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class will not cause other pods to be preempted."
```

Also, I have inspected the nodes and their node-pressure conditions. All the pressure conditions return as false, so I don’t believe this is caused by node-pressure eviction.

Below is an example of a pod that has this behaviour:

```
---
spec:
  dnsPolicy: None
  priorityClassName: high-priority-nonpreempting
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: imageuri
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 2
        memory: 4G
  restartPolicy: Never
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
    - 8.8.8.8
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: zone
            values:
            - zone-1
            operator: In
      - weight: 90
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: zone
            values:
            - zone-2
            operator: In
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: testingpod
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
```

Comment: Please share the (or an example) job yaml that presents with this symptom so your scenario can be replicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If a pod is already scheduled and running on a node, [IgnoredDuringExecution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) suggests that it shouldn't be removed because a node's labels changed at runtime; instead, only new pods should be required to meet the updated requirements.

If a pod [uses more resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/) than the node truly has available, it will be evicted.